# Bank of wall outlets not working

Tags: electrical-distribution

I have a bank of wall outlets that are not working. I have checked the fuses and found all of them check ok at 120 v ac. I then replaced all three outlets with new ones and still have no power. I did check the power on all of the lines to each outlet and found no power to every socket. (There are three). I then went to the attic where the line goes into the wall and traced the line to the power source and found no breaks that I could see or identify. So now I am stuck????

Comment: Sounds similar to an issue I had - http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/56359/what-is-causing-my-electric-problems

Answer (score 1):

If the line from the wall to the power source is good, and the power source is good, then the problem will be in the wall.  It's hard to imagine how something could go wrong between the top of the wall and the outlet, but I had this very problem once and traced it to a mystery, unclosed box with the two unterminated wires in it in the middle of the wall for who-knows-what reason, completely hidden by drywall.

Is there a switch on this wall as well?  If so, the outlets are probably connected there to the power source.  If not, your best bet may be to start at the outlet and trace the wire back to the source through the wall.  This will involve removing wall covering, and the repairs and cleanup that that entails.